# Как найти функцию в дизассемблированном коде через ollydebug

Tags: delphi, ассемблер, x86, ollydbg

Есть программа написанная на Delphi. В этой программе есть компонент stringgrid, из базы данных копируются текст в строки таблицы.

Вопрос как в отладчике ollydebug найти место в коде, где этот компонент начинает работать, место где этот компонент рисуется в форме.

Хочу вырезать этот код.

Comment: а зачем? вполне возможно, что "вырезав этот код", Вы сломаете больше кода. Да, на Ваш вопрос можно ответить, но это тема целого списка статей, а не ответ на пару абзацев

Comment: @KoVadim был бы признателен Вам за любую информацию. Можно просто ссылку.

Comment: @KoVadim возможно и сломаю, возможно нет, не попробую-не узнаю. Исходного кода нет, с нуля писать программу не вариант, для этого и хочу корректировать уже существующую, мертвую, не поддерживаемую программу. Тем более что нужно не переписывать, а просто занопить или поставить переход в другое место. Я вкурсе что это возможно из примеров того что можно делать ассемблерные вставки вспоминается известный мод игры Age of Empires, в котором был дописан дополнительный функционал.

Comment: тогда Вам на сайты взломщиков. А тут это немного оффтоп.